# How do we purify our heart and soul and how long does it take?

Tags: spirituality

How long does it take for the purification of our heart and spirit  and what we need to do in order to purify it?

Comment: here: https://islamqa.info/en/34306

Answer (score 1):

Purification of heart and soul is only possible by following Kitab (The Noble Quraan) wa Sunnah (The lifestyle of the Messenger of Allah saw and his companions). To remain it, you need to save yourself from disobeying Allah and his Messenger saw.

To purify our heart we can zikr more and more. But, beware of innovated amals. Only practice those zikr which is proven from Kitab wa Sunnah.

I am quoting some points you need to follow to achieve purification of heart and soul.

**1.** Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “Shall I not tell you of something that will take away the evil of the
>   heart? Fasting three days of each month.”

(Narrated by al-Nasaa’i, 2386; classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Nasaa’i, 2249)

**2.** Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “No one will enter Paradise who has an atom’s-weight of arrogance in
>   his heart.”

(Narrated by Muslim, 91)

**3.**

> “On the Day of Resurrection the arrogant will be gathered like ants in
>   the form of men.”

(Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 2492; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 2025)

**4.** Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “The disease of the nations who came before you has started to spread
>   among you: destructive envy and hatred. These are the shavers. I do
>   not mean that they shave hair but they shave away religious
>   commitment. By the One in Whose hand is my soul, you will not enter
>   Paradise until you believe, and you will not believe until you love
>   one another. Shall I not tell you of something which if you do it, you
>   will love one another. Spread (the greeting of) salaam amongst
>   yourselves.”

(Narrated by al-Tirmidhi, 2510; classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Tirmidhi, 2038).

> “and put not in our hearts any hatred against those who have believed”

[al-Hashr 59:10 – interpretation of the meaning]

**5.**

> “There is not one of you but will pass over it (Hell); this is with
>   your Lord, a Decree which must be accomplished.
>
> Then We shall save those who use to fear Allaah and were dutiful to
>   Him. And We shall leave the Zaalimoon (polytheists and wrongdoers)
>   therein (humbled) to their knees (in Hell)”

[Maryam 19:71-72]

**6.** Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “When a man dies all his good deeds come to an end except three:
>   ongoing charity, beneficial knowledge and a righteous child who will
>   pray for him.”

Narrated by Muslim, 1638.

**7.** The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said:

> “I have only been sent to perfect good characteristics.”

Narrated by al-Bukhaari in al-Adab al-Mufrad (273)

**8.**  It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) was asked about that which will admit most people to Paradise. He said:

> “Fear of Allaah and a good attitude.”

Narrated by al-Tirmidhi (2004)

**9.**

> By the declining day, (1) Lo! man is a state of loss, (2) Save those
>   who believe and do good works, and exhort one another to truth and
>   exhort one another to endurance. (3)

[Surah Asr]